Java Swing WrapLayout can't wrap correctly while resizing
Here is a simple example code about my question, you can run it with MigLayout.
public class TestFrame extends JFrame
{

    public TestFrame()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 500));
        JTabbedPane pane = new JTabbedPane();
        pane.addTab("TestFrame", new Panel1());
        add(pane);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * level-1 panel, also contains other components
     * I just add incorrect panel(Panel2) here
     */
    class Panel1 extends JPanel
    {

        public Panel1()
        {
            MigLayout layout = new MigLayout();
            setLayout(layout);
            add(new Panel2(), new CC().cell(0, 0).growX().pushX());
        }

    }

    /**
     * level-2 panel, also contains other components
     * I just add incorrect panel(CheckBoxesPanel) here
     */
    class Panel2 extends JPanel
    {
        public Panel2()
        {
            MigLayout layout = new MigLayout();
            setLayout(layout);
            add(new CheckBoxesPanel(), new CC().cell(0, 0).growX().pushX());
        }
    }

    class CheckBoxesPanel extends JPanel
    {

        public CheckBoxesPanel()
        {
            WrapLayout layout = new WrapLayout(WrapLayout.LEADING);
            setLayout(layout);
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                add(new JCheckBox("JCB" + i));
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new TestFrame();
    }


    class WrapLayout extends FlowLayout
    {

        public WrapLayout()
        {
            super();
        }

        public WrapLayout(int align)
        {
            super(align);
        }

        public WrapLayout(int align, int hGap, int vGap)
        {
            super(align, hGap, vGap);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container target)
        {
            return layoutSize(target, true);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container target)
        {
            Dimension minimum = layoutSize(target, false);
            minimum.width -= (getHgap() + 1);
            return minimum;
        }

        private Dimension layoutSize(Container target, boolean preferred)
        {
            synchronized (target.getTreeLock())
            {
                Container container = target;

                while (container.getSize().width == 0 && container.getParent() != null)
                {
                    container = container.getParent();
                }

                int targetWidth = container.getSize().width;
                if (targetWidth == 0)
                {
                    return new Dimension();
                }

                int hGap = getHgap();
                int vGap = getVgap();
                Insets insets = target.getInsets();
                int horizontalInsetsAndGap = insets.left + insets.right + (hGap * 2);
                int maxWidth = targetWidth - horizontalInsetsAndGap;

                Dimension dim = new Dimension(0, 0);
                int rowWidth = 0;
                int rowHeight = 0;

                int count = target.getComponentCount();

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    Component m = target.getComponent(i);

                    if (m.isVisible())
                    {
                        Dimension d = preferred ? m.getPreferredSize() : m.getMinimumSize();

                        if (rowWidth + d.width >= maxWidth)
                        {
                            addRow(dim, rowWidth, rowHeight);
                            rowWidth = 0;
                            rowHeight = 0;
                        }

                        if (rowWidth != 0)
                        {
                            rowWidth += hGap;
                        }

                        rowWidth += d.width;
                        rowHeight = Math.max(rowHeight, d.height);
                    }
                }

                addRow(dim, rowWidth, rowHeight);

                dim.width += horizontalInsetsAndGap;
                dim.height += insets.top + insets.bottom + vGap * 2;

                Container scrollPane = SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JScrollPane.class, target);

                if (scrollPane != null && target.isValid())
                {
                    dim.width -= (hGap + 1);
                }
                return dim;
            }
        }

        private void addRow(Dimension dim, int rowWidth, int rowHeight)
        {
            dim.width = Math.max(dim.width, rowWidth);

            if (dim.height > 0)
            {
                dim.height += getVgap();
            }

            dim.height += rowHeight;
        }
    }

}

I found that when I dragged slowly, the program wrapped correctly. There will be problems if dragging too fast.
Here are the GIFs of the correct and incorrect cases.
Correct wrap case
and
Incorrect wrap case
This seems to be related to the minimum size calculation, but I don't know how to solve this problem.

Works fine when I change the layout manager of panel1 and panel2 to use a BorderLayout, instead of the MigLayout. I don't know anything about the MigLayout but I would expect you would want both the x/y to grow to fill the available space.

@camickr You can think of MigLayout as an enhanced GridBagLayout, and I add a link for it. I tried what you said and it worked fine. But there will be other components in  panel1 and panel2, so the situation will be more complex. I feel that BorderLayout cannot meet my requirements.

I wasn't necessarily suggesting you use the BorderLayout. The point was that when you use a layout manager that allocates space in both the x/y directions the WrapLayout works as expected. So if you want to use MigLayout, then you need to add the proper constraints to provide this behaviour. Or the other option is to nest the standard JDK layout managers to achieve you desired layout. You are not forced to use a singleLayout manager.
